# How to find solution of $P(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{A^2}{4}\{\delta(f-f_c)+\delta(f+f_c)\}df$

Tags: integration

I want to find the solution of below function
$$P(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{A^2}{4}\{\delta(f-f_c)+\delta(f+f_c)\}df$$

where $A,f_c$ are const.

This is my solution

Due to
 $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(f)\delta(f-f_c)df=g(f_c)$$
Then, $g(f)=\frac{A^2}{4}$
$$P(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(f)\{\delta(f-f_c)+\delta(f+f_c)\}df$$
$$P(f)=g(f_c)+g(-f_c)=\frac{A^2}{2}$$

Is it correct?

How about if I change function such as
$$P(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{A^2f^2}{4}\{\delta(f-f_c)+\delta(f+f_c)\}df$$
then 
$$P(f)=g(f_c)+g(-f_c)=\frac{A^2f_c^2}{2}$$
Is it correct?

Comment: There are a lot of variables I think you did not define. How did you get $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(f)\delta(f-f_c)df=g(f_c)$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Comment: It looks correct.